# How to show line numbers for every 10 lines?

Tags: delphi, synedit

The `SynEdit` control has an event `OnGutterGetText`. I would like to use this to make the gutter only display every 10th line number (also line 1 and currently selected line). The same way that the Delphi (XE7) IDE works. How do I determine whether to show the line or not using this event?

Comment: The event supplies you the line number. Surely that's all you need.

Comment: @David Of course, what I'm asking is how to do the actual math to determine whether it should show.

Comment: `if (lineNum mod 10) = 0 then xxxx`

Comment: @Graymatter Thanks, I knew it was something like `mod` - I'm terrible with that side of math.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question transpires to be nothing to do with the edit control in reality. You simply want to know if `a` is an exact multiple of `b`. That is so if the remainder of `a` divided by `b` is zero. And the remainder operator in Delphi is [`mod`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Expressions_(Delphi)#Arithmetic_Operators).

```
if a mod b = 0 then
```

Now, in your case you want

```
if LineNum mod 10 = 0 then
```

This assumes that `LineNum` is one based. If it is zero based then you need

```
if (LineNum + 1) mod 10 = 0 then
```